# vb.net form freezing, threading, events and a confused noob

Tags: vb.net, forms, events, thread-safety

I’ve got a problem with form freezes when loading the form from an event. I bet it got to do with threading but sadly I don’t know enough about it to fix it myself :(

Let me explain my project:
I've got a class that hooks into networking events (like new connected e.g.),
which I’ve instanced in a form and declared some events from it.

```
Public Netstat As New aaNetTool.clsNetworkStatus  

AddHandler Netstat.NetworkChanged, AddressOf Network_Changed

Sub Network_Changed()

End Sub
```

Then I’ve written another class, clsMessage which I want to use to show forms with notifications.

```
Public Class clsMessage
    Private myForm As frmDisplayMessage

    Public Sub New(ByVal Title$, ByVal Text$, Optional btnYesAction As Action = Nothing, Optional ByVal ShowTimeSec% = 10)
        myForm = New frmDisplayMessage
        myForm.Text = Title
        myForm.lblText.Text = Text
        (...)
        myForm.Show()
        (...)
    End Sub
```

Now I create a new notification window for debugging purposes with a button from the main form like this:

```
Dim myMsg As New clsMessage("title", "text", AddressOf MapNetworkdrives, 30)
```

This works like a charm.

But when I call the notification from my declared event:

```
Sub Network_Changed()
         Dim myMsg As New clsMessage("title", "text", AddressOf MapNetworkdrives, 30)
End Sub
```

The form with the notification appears but is empty and freezed.
As said before I think this may have to do with my code running on different threads but I just can't figure out how to solve this :(

Thanks in advance for your Time,

Lunex

Comment: What does it show you if you put `MessageBox.Show(Me.InvokeRequired.ToString())` in your `Network_Changed` method?

Comment: IT shows InvokeRequired = true - so its a threading thing, right?

Comment: Yeah, it means that the `Network_Changed` method is run in a different thread and you must invoke to access the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clsNetworkStatus.NetworkChanged` event appears to be raised from a background thread. Since your notification form is part of the UI you must invoke so that it is executed under the UI thread.

The [**`InvokeRequired` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx) tells you whether you need to invoke or not, so if it's `False` your code is already running on the UI thread.

You can create an extension method to do the checking for you:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Extensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub InvokeIfRequired(ByVal Control As Control, ByVal Method As Action)
        If Control.InvokeRequired = True Then
            Control.Invoke(Method) 'Invoke the method thread-safely.
        Else
            Method.Invoke() 'Call the method normally (equal to just calling: 'Method()').
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
Sub Network_Changed()
     Me.InvokeIfRequired(Sub()
                                           Dim myMsg As New clsMessage("title", "text", AddressOf MapNetworkdrives, 30)
                                       End Sub)
End Sub
```

Comment: 'Me.InvokeIfRequired(Sub() **Dim myMsg As New clsMessage("title", "text", AddressOf MapNetworkdrives, 30))**'
the bold part throws an error Statement is not valid inside a single-line statement

Comment: also, I know how to invoke a simple command - but how to invoke the declaration & instantiation of a class with parameters?

Comment: @Lunex : No problem! Glad I could help, and good luck with your project!

Comment: so I just have to check if invoke is required, and if so call a new sub with my code with .invoke(mySub), right?

Comment: @Lunex : I don't know what you mean with "new sub", but if `InvokeRequired` is **True:** `<control here>.Invoke(mySub)`, **False:** `mySub()`.

Comment: @Lunex : You can use the extension method to save code.